# Is there a way of extracting a selection into a partial or another view either in VS 2013 Editor or Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, resharper

Is there a way of selecting HTML or razor code in the VS Editor and extract it into a separate view file?

Visual Studio 2013 already has a similar feature in WebForms where code selection can be extracted into a UserControl. Also, RubyMine, Resharper's sister product, has a "Extract Partial View" feature that extracts code into a separate view file.

I'd wager that such a feature exists in either product, but I haven't been able to find it. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-263354](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-263354#tab=History)

Doesn't look like it will be possible any time soon unfortunately